# Как созданы стандартные функции php?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Недавно возник вопрос: хотел бы узнать, есть ли какие нибудь ресурсы и .т.д., где можно посмотреть, как были созданы стандартные функции php, ну, то есть, например, функция count. Как она была создана, из каких элементарных операторов она состоит?

Comment: К сожалению, в папке php есть данные в основном по zend, про раскрытие стандартных функций ничего нет. Всем спс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

зайдите [сюда](http://php.net/downloads.php), скачайте сорцы, потом по ним ищите любую функцию, которую хочется.

Comment: Ок щяс посмотрим..СПС

Comment: Скачал, но не нахожу папку; знаете, в какой папке она?

Comment: В архиве находим папку `/php-5.2.17/ext/standard/`, а в ней файлик array.c. Начиная с 311 строки будет реализация функции count.
Найти любую другую функцию можно по строке PHP_FUNCTION(имя функции).

Answer (score 1):

[Исходный код PHP](http://www.php.net/downloads.php)

Answer (score 0):

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php)

[php.su](http://php.su/functions/?count)

Comment: Извините, вы неправильно поняли: мне не нужна документация, как они работают.)) Люди, которые создали эти стандартные функции php, они создали их из обычных операторов примитивных и соединили это всё в функцию, которую не надо придумывать. И просто пишем, а она делает.) Интересно знать, как они работают, из чего они состоят. ) Спс заранее.

Comment: Речь не только о count относится ко всем стандартным функциям

Comment: Никогда с такими ресурсами не встречался. Есть ли они вообще.
Покопайте папку php, мб там они все и описаны.

Comment: PHP "написан" на C , значит копать нужно ещё глубже.

Comment: Спс щяс посмотрим..

Comment: Да, в папке php только про zend, остального нет. ( Но ничего, все равно спс.

Comment: покопался идой в файлах папки php5\ext
нашел описания ероров, название нек функций, бм если заюзать хексрэйс будет на что посмотреть. Так что экспериментируйте.